# Calculating difference in time

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

In table first value I have value with `datatype = Start`

I need to calculate difference `first value - midnight`

Last value is with `datatype =Stop`

I need to calculate difference `midnight - last item`

For other I need to calculate `datatype.Stop - previous.datatype=Start`

Here is ViewModel that I use for repo method

```
public class HeatMapViewModel
{
    public decimal? Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public int coeff = 2;
    public int Difference;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote this code in repo method

```
public List<HeatMapViewModel> GetStops()
{
    using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
    {
        List<HeatMapViewModel> items = new List<HeatMapViewModel>();

        var firstitem = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

        var midnight = new DateTime(firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Year, firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Month, firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
        TimeSpan difference = (firstitem.CurrentDateTime - midnight);
        var difference_after_midnight = (int)difference.TotalMinutes;

        items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
        {
            Latitude2 = firstitem.Latitude,
            Longitude2 = firstitem.Longitude,
            Difference = difference_after_midnight,
            Date = firstitem.CurrentDateTime
        });

       var lastItem = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
       var before_midnight = new DateTime(lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Year, lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Month, lastItem.CurrentDateTime.Day, 23, 59, 00);
       TimeSpan difference_before = (before_midnight - lastItem.CurrentDateTime);
       var difference_before_midnight = (int)difference_before.TotalMinutes;

       items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
       {
            Latitude2 = lastItem.Latitude,
            Longitude2 = lastItem.Longitude,
            Difference = difference_before_midnight,
            Date = firstitem.CurrentDateTime
        });

        var allitems = ctx.Logging;
        var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start || x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogID).ToList();

        for (int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++)
        {
            if (filteredQuery[i].Datatype == Datatype.Stop && filteredQuery[i - 1].Datatype == Datatype.Start)
            {
                TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i - 1].CurrentDateTime - filteredQuery[i].CurrentDateTime;

                items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
                {
                    Latitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Latitude,
                    Longitude2 = filteredQuery[i].Longitude,
                    Difference = (int)differenceTicks.TotalMinutes,
                    Date = firstitem.CurrentDateTime
                });
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Here is data from db

[image]
It works great, but I need to know if I can modify it?

Comment: There are a few changes you can make to both simplify this and improve performance (for example, you making 3 database calls when you only need one) but without seeing a sample of your database records and how this data is being used it a bit hard to give an answer.

Comment: And you have not specified an `.OrderBy()` clause so there is no guarantee that the result will be returned in the order your expecting

Comment: I updated my  post @StephenMuecke

Comment: What do the numbers `0`, `1` and `2` relate to (i.e. which is `Start` and which is `Stop` and what is the other value for)? The fact that most records in your table image have `0` and only a few have `1` or `2` and there seems to be no order to them would potentially cause problems with your query - and at the very least its very inefficient.

Comment: 1- Start, 2 -  Stop, 0 -Driving.

For 0 is other method. I working with 1 and 2 @StephenMuecke

Comment: OK (that's what I guessed but wasn't sure). And I scrolled across and just noticed your `OrderByDescending()` clause so you can ignore my 2nd comment. I'll add an answer tomorrow with a few suggested improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main area where you code can be improved is in your database calls. Currently your making 3 database calls. When you use

```
var lastItem = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
```

your loading all the records into memory (using `.AsEnumerable()`) in order to get the last one then throwing all the rest away, and then making another database query using

```
var filteredQuery = allitems.Where(...)
```

which fetches those records all over again. You only need the one database call to materialize the records to memory, and then you can get the first and last records from that collection.

Your also not testing for `null` when you use `.FirstOrDefault()` and `.LastOrDefault()` which has the potential to throw an exception in the code following those queries.

You can also simplify some code such as

```
var midnight = new DateTime(firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Year, firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Month, firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
```

which can be rewritten as

```
var midnight = firstitem.CurrentDateTime.Date;
```

You could re-write your method to have only one database call as

```
public List<HeatMapViewModel> GetStops()
{
    using (TraxgoDB ctx = new TraxgoDB())
    {
        List<HeatMapViewModel> items = new List<HeatMapViewModel>();
        var logs = ctx.Logging.Where(x => x.Datatype == Datatype.Start || x.Datatype == Datatype.Stop).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogID).ToList();
        if (logs.Count < 2)
        {
            return items; // or return null;?
        }
        var first = logs.First();
        var currentDateTime = first.CurrentDateTime;
        double minutes = (first.CurrentDateTime - first.CurrentDateTime.Date).TotalMinutes;
        items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
        {
            Latitude2 = first.Latitude,
            Longitude2 = first.Longitude,
            Difference = (int)minutes,
            Date = currentDateTime
        });
        var last = logs.Last();
        minutes = (last.CurrentDateTime.Date.AddDays(1) - last.CurrentDateTime).TotalMinutes;
        items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
        {
            Latitude2 = last.Latitude,
            Longitude2 = last.Longitude,
            Difference = (int)minutes,
            Date = currentDateTime
        });
        for (int i = 1; i < logs.Count; i++)
        {
            var previous = logs[i - 1];
            var current = logs[i];
            if (current.Datatype == Datatype.Stop && previous.Datatype == Datatype.Start)
            {
                minutes = (previous.CurrentDateTime - current.CurrentDateTime).TotalMinutes;

                items.Add(new HeatMapViewModel
                {
                    Latitude2 = current.Latitude,
                    Longitude2 = current.Longitude,
                    Difference = (int)minutes,
                    Date = currentDateTime
                });
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Note that I have assumed that if there were less than 2 items in the table, then your data would not make sense in a view which is the purpose of `if (logs.Count < 2)`. That check will also prevent exceptions in the code that follows.

I have also assumed (based on the description in the question) that `.First()` will always return an item with `DataType.Start` and `.Last()` will always return an item with `DataType.Stop` so I have excluded checks for that in the code above